# Why use move_base when mapping?

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I studied the tutorial [SLAM Map Building with TurtleBot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/indigo/Build a map with SLAM) and tutorial [Mapping and Navigation with Turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot), I found that `move_base` is used in their launch files. My understanding is that when building a map, the robot is controlled by the keyboard.Why use `move_base`? What does `move_base` do here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341286/why-use-move_base-when-mapping?/) by [willzoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/50793/willzoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends. If you teleop your robot to explore the area you do not need move_base.

But you could also make the robot automatically explore the area, e.g. using [frontier exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration). This would require all nodes for autonomous navigation.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [willzoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/50793/willzoe/) on 2020-01-09**:
Thanks.
By the way, if I want to use the navigation stack to create my own navigation package, which packages should I add as dependencies? Is it possible to directly add `navigation` or `turtlebot_navigation` as a dependency?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2020-01-09**:
Please open a new question for that. If you are the only one using this package I would not bother. If others should use it please add only the required packages.